# Changing Polyline Google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination +"&alternatives=true" +"&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;

EDITED :
I have that on my code that will enable to display the shortest route along with the alternative routes. My problem is, is that the shortest route and alternative routes have the same color which is blue. How can I change the colors of my alternative route different than the shortest route?
 Please help. I'm very new to this. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can determine the color of a polyline like this

```
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                    .addAll(list)
                                    .width(MAP_POLYLINE_WIDTH)
                                    .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb")) //
                                    .geodesic(true)
                                );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if the color that I want for my shortest path is let's say example, blue and the alternative paths as grey? All I know is that google map can parse a max of 4 routes 1 search. The result I had in doing this is all 4 routes are blue which can be confusing for the user's end. Do you know how to do so?